# Python FTPLIB 425 Can't build data connection: Connection timed out

Tags: python, ftplib

This used to work :

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(os.environ.get('FTP_IP'))  
ftp.login(os.environ.get('FTP_LOGIN'),os.environ.get('FTP_PASS')) 
ftp.set_pasv(False)  
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
file = open(file,'rb')   # file to send
ftp.storbinary('STOR myFile.csv', file)
```

But during an update on the receiver side (NAS) I now get the following:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(os.environ.get('FTP_IP'))  --> WORKS
ftp.login(os.environ.get('FTP_LOGIN'),os.environ.get('FTP_PASS')) --> WORKS
ftp.set_pasv(False)  
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
file = open(file,'rb')   # file to send
ftp.storbinary('STOR myFile.csv', file)  --> FAILS with following logs
*get* '200 PORT command successful.\n'
*resp* '200 PORT command successful.'
*cmd* 'STOR myFile.csv'
*put* 'STOR myFile.csv\r\n'
*get* "425 Can't build data connection: Connection timed out.\n"
*resp* "425 Can't build data connection: Connection timed out."
```

Any idea on how to solve this? OR why I can't execute any FTP commands like LIST

The logs that I get when pasv is set to True:

```
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*get* '200 Type set to I.\n'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,20)\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,20)'
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Many FTP problems are caused by firewalls etc. Is there a particular reason you are disabling `PASV`?

Comment: This used to make it work. Now this line doesn't do the trick anymore.

Comment: What does the debug output look like? How does it change if you enable passive mode?

Comment: I get the following logs: 
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*put* 'TYPE I\r\n'
*get* '200 Type set to I.\n'
*resp* '200 Type set to I.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (XXXX)\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (XXXX)'
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: And when you disable passive mode? Please [edit] the question to update it rather than hide these debugging details in comments; you'll also have better facilities for formatting this information.

Comment: The XXXX information you removed is the interesting part. Can you connect to the indicated port by other means?

Comment: Correct the XXX, indicates port 20, but only port 21 is setup to establish the connection! Thanks @tripleee !